# Why not all DLL modules I can load (open)?

Tags: c++, c, windows, dll

I have notepad.exe path and I need to output all DLL modules and functions that notepad.exe uses (imports).

```
  int InitWork()
{
    LPCWSTR fileName = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe";

    PEinfo.handle = CreateFile(fileName, GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING,  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0); 

    /*....*/
    PVOID pVirtual = VirtualAlloc(NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
    /*...*/
    // Get pointer to headers
    PEinfo. pNTHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(PCHAR(pVirtual) + PEinfo.pDOSHead->e_lfanew);   
    PEinfo.pSech = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(PEinfo.pNTHeader);
    PEinfo.OptHeader32 = (IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER32) PEinfo.pNTHeader->OptionalHeader; 

    WCHAR* funcname = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t));

    size_t i=0;
    LPSTR libname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    if(PEinfo.OptHeader32.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].Size != 0)
    {
        PEinfo.pImportDescriptor = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR)((DWORD_PTR)pVirtual +\
            Rva2Offset(PEinfo.OptHeader32.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT].VirtualAddress,PEinfo.pSech,PEinfo.pNTHeader));

        printf("DLLName.FunctionName\n");

        while(PEinfo.pImportDescriptor->Name != NULL)
        {           
            //Get the name of each DLL
            libname = (PCHAR)((DWORD_PTR)pVirtual + Rva2Offset(PEinfo.pImportDescriptor->Name,PEinfo.pSech,PEinfo.pNTHeader));

            funcname = ANSItoUnicode(libname, funcname);

            ImportFuncList(funcname);
            PEinfo.pImportDescriptor++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/*Convert Virtual Address to File Offset */
DWORD Rva2Offset(DWORD rva,PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER psh,PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS pnt)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER pSeh;
    if(rva == 0)
    {
        return (rva);
    }
    pSeh = psh;
    for(i = 0; i < pnt->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        if(rva >= pSeh->VirtualAddress && rva < pSeh->VirtualAddress +
            pSeh->Misc.VirtualSize)
        {
            break;
        }
        pSeh++;
    }
    return (rva - pSeh->VirtualAddress + pSeh->PointerToRawData);
} 

int ImportFuncList(LPWSTR dllName)
{
    PEinfo.DLLModule = NULL;
    PEinfo.DLLModule = GetModuleHandle(dllName);

    if (PEinfo.DLLModule == NULL)
    {
        wprintf(L"Error Load %s\n", dllName);
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Result:
ADVAPI32.dll.
KERNEL32.dll.
GDI32.dll.
USER32.dll.
msvcrt.dll.
Error Load COMDLG32.dll
Error Load SHELL32.dll
Error Load WINSPOOL.DRV
Error Load ole32.dll
Error Load SHLWAPI.dll
Error Load COMCTL32.dll
Error Load OLEAUT32.dll
ntdll.dll.
Error Load VERSION.dll

What the?

Why some DLL loaded and some didn't???

Comment: It might not be in the same path or it might be corrupted or may be a registry problem see this for getting an idea how to solve this.http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/comdlg32-dll-not-found-missing-error.htm

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `GetModuleHandle`? What makes you think all the referenced DLLs have been loaded?

Comment: `WCHAR* funcname = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t));` and  `LPSTR libname = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));` - both these initializations are too small and neither of them is required. Initialize them both to zero.

Comment: Carey Gregory, yes, you are right about number of DLL. Not all of them loaded, just 14/23 according to OllyDBG. And I'm waiting 90 minutes to post a question about it)

Comment: EJP, libname is working fine. filName looks another in real program. I cut it for question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modules that are failing simply haven't been loaded yet. Do this and I predict your code will work as expected:

```
LoadLibrary(dllName);
PEinfo.DLLModule = GetModuleHandle(dllName);
```

This isn't how you should do this, but it demonstrates the point that DLLs aren't all loaded on program startup, and if they haven't been loaded yet, `GetModuleHandle` will fail.

Comment: How should I do it (I mean how should i load functions from dll)?

Comment: I just meant it's probably not a good idea to load DLLs for another program. Some apps reference hundreds of DLLs, many of which will never be loaded in normal operation, but if you force load them all it could be quite a performance problem. But if you absolutely must know that not only does the app reference DLL x but it also _can_ load that DLL, then you'll have to use `LoadLibrary`. I would expect that for most purposes just knowing that the app references a DLL would be good enough.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I thought about 'LoadLibrary' but than saw something new and tried it.